# Python GTK 3+: How to center text within Combobox widget?

Tags: python, gtk3

So I have a Combobox and I want to center the inner text (Right now it's all pushed to the left). However, I can't seem to find a function to do this nor can I seem to touch it through the CSS. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: If my answer worked, please mark it as working so other people coming here know that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the popular Gtk Combobox example and modified it to show how to center the text:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ComboBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="ComboBox Example")

        self.set_border_width(10)

        name_store = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
        name_store.append([1, "Billy Bob"])
        name_store.append([11, "Billy Bob Junior"])
        name_store.append([12, "Sue Bob"])
        name_store.append([2, "Joey Jojo"])
        name_store.append([3, "Rob McRoberts"])
        name_store.append([31, "Xavier McRoberts"])

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)

        name_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(name_store)
        name_combo.connect("changed", self.on_name_combo_changed)
        name_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
        vbox.pack_start(name_combo, False, False, 0)

        country_store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        countries = ["Austria", "Brazil", "Belgium", "France", "Germany",
        "Switzerland", "United Kingdom", "United States of America",
        "Uruguay"]
        for country in countries:
            country_store.append([country])

        country_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(country_store)
        country_combo.connect("changed", self.on_country_combo_changed)
        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        renderer_text.set_property("xalign", 0.51) #less than 0.51 has no affect
        country_combo.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
        country_combo.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)

        vbox.pack_start(country_combo, False, False, True)

        currencies = ["Euro", "US Dollars", "British Pound", "Japanese Yen",
        "Russian Ruble", "Mexican peso", "Swiss franc"]
        currency_combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
        currency_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
        currency_combo.connect("changed", self.on_currency_combo_changed)
        for currency in currencies:
            currency_combo.append_text(currency)

        vbox.pack_start(currency_combo, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)

    def on_name_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is not None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            row_id, name = model[tree_iter][:2]
            print("Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name))
        else:
            entry = combo.get_child()
            print("Entered: %s" % entry.get_text())

    def on_country_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is not None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            country = model[tree_iter][0]
            print("Selected: country=%s" % country)

    def on_currency_combo_changed(self, combo):
        text = combo.get_active_text()
        if text is not None:
            print("Selected: currency=%s" % text)

win = ComboBoxWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Hello again. If I want to use CSS styling on the same combobox (Example: counrtry_combo). How do I apply the same CSS styling to the entire thing? For instance, if I want to make the highlighted part of dropdown (by default blue) green instead, how do I do that? I have a CSS file set up but I seem to be having a hard time touching the inner parts of the combobox.

Comment: You are asking a new question. Please post a new question with what you just explained here. This will keep this site clean and organized.